# Skip driver loading during WIndows boot

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bitlocker

I have a big problem: My Windows 10 gives a BSOD on startup because of a new audio driver I installed. 
I can't go into safe mode to disable it, because I seem to have lost the Bitlocker recovery key. According to our admin this key should be saved in the AD, but it's not there.

I'm not asking how to 'defeat' bitlocker, I simply want to know if it's possible to make Windows skip loading the drivers during startup, e.g. by pressing the SHIFT key or something. I don't have many other options - even the recovery command prompt can't access my Windows drive

If that's not possible I'll have to install Windows again.
Is it possible to do so without formatting the entire drive? (There are other partitions on it that are not encrypted - I would like to keep them)

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: without knowing the bitlocker key you can't do anything

Comment: Allright, so what do I do then? Is it enough to simply format the Windows partition? Will that remove Bitlocker?

Comment: yes, [look at this question](https://superuser.com/q/408809/174557)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part of the question involving booting into Windows without drivers without having to provide the Bitlocker recovery key, I can share the following experience (if it helps any future readers):

I work on a Windows 10 machine that has Bitlocker installed. I have been able to enter "Safe Mode" without entering the Bitlocker recovery key. I **did** however, have to enter the Bitlocker PIN (6 digit number). It sounds like the original poster knows the PIN (otherwise how did he/she login to Windows to install the audio driver?) but if someone else reads this and does not know the PIN or the recovery key, then sorry, I can't help you.

Microsoft has web pages and community forum topics with information on entering Safe Mode with Bitlocker installed, but everything I read said to press F8 repeatedly before Bitlocker launches. In my case, I have a USB keyboard with Windows drivers and the OS is on a super-fast SSD, so the number of times I have successfully pressed F8 repeatedly between when the keyboard lights up and when the Bitlocker screen suddenly appears has been 0/10 attempts. Someone with a keyboard connected to a PS/2 keyboard port might do better.

However, you can also use the "System Configuration App" to set the machine to always boot into Safe Mode (on the boot) tab. It is necessary to come back later and switch this back or else you will continue to always boot into safe mode.

Once you have made the boot setting change using System Configuration app and rebooted, Bitlocker will provide options to enter the account recovery key or to just enter the pin. Entering the pin should get you into Safe Mode. That's what I did. Once you have done whatever you were going to do in safe mode, go back to System Configuration app and change the boot options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Win 10 has disabled menu under F8 during startup by default.
Enable it via command first:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

Comment: It is not clear, whether the curly braces are meant to be typed in or substituted.  Also, consider providing a reference for it.