# Deleted All Partitions and can't use drive anymore

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

I had a drive that was asking for a bitlocker recovery key.
I went to the link below and ended up using the CMD Delete partition override to delete all of the partitions, including system, recovery, and reserved.
[How to format a drive encrypted with Bitlocker?](https://superuser.com/questions/408809/how-to-format-a-drive-encrypted-with-bitlocker)

I thought it would be fine since I was going to reinstall windows using a boot usb, but now the drive isn't showing up during the installation process.
I can't go back to the CMD troubleshooting unless the boot usb is plugged in.
When I use diskpart, list disk, it only lists the usb and not the old drive.

If I boot without the usb, I get a page that says boot device bit found. Hard disk (3F0), and an option to go to Sys Diagnostics by pressing F2.
I've done a quick and extensive check on all harddrives, but it has passed them both.
I think it is still detecting the original drive since it lists 2 NVMe drives.
One is 512 and the other is 29gb.

I installed aoemei partition assistant, created a bootable USB, plugged that into the laptop, but only the windows bootable USB is showing up.

Comment: Do you have CSM enabled or disabled?

Comment: I don't see CSM anywhere in BIOS.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but this is an HP laptop

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the TPM if it's got one, if so, see if you can wipe it in the BIOS/UEFI. You could try booting from a Linux disk, and see if that sees the disk, then use dd to wipe it.

Comment: I cleared TPM but that didn't seem to fix anything. I will try booting from a linux disk later, but I just wanted to mention that I can't open BIOS without the bootable USB for windows. I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: So I was able to install ubuntu to the SSD, but how do I use dd to wipe it?