# Bios is pasword protected dont have password

Tags: bios, windows-11, bitlocker

I am trying to repurpose a 2022 Lenovo thinkpad.

- I don't have the password to enter bios.
- The USB ports are turned off in bios
- There's no dvd player
- And the thumbdrive 2 slots are turned off.
- I'm getting the BitLocker screen asking for a password.

How do I reload Win 11. & get by no access to the bios? I took off the back of the laptop. I could not find a bios battery there was no bios clear jumper. Maybe it's on the bottom of the motherboad?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can’t reset the firmware passwords on most laptops.

Comment: If you bought it from a reputable source, send it back. If you bought it from 'a man in the pub' you were done.

Answer (score 3):

If the disk is locked with Bitlocker, then it doesn't matter if you
have the BIOS/UEFI password or not - there is no way for you to
ever decrypt the data that is encrypted with Bitlocker.

This is evidently a second-hand laptop, and the owner was very
secretive about his data.

You absolutely need to get the Bitlocker password or key from the
previous owner, as well as the BIOS password. Without both, this
computer is useless to you.

The Bitlocker password can possibly be worked around following the
post
[How to format a drive encrypted with Bitlocker?](https://superuser.com/questions/408809/how-to-format-a-drive-encrypted-with-bitlocker)
This will wipe out everything on the disk and require to reinstall
Windows from scratch. The only good news is that Windows will
activate itself automatically.

For the BIOS password, we will need the exact model of your computer,
but the chances are very low that it could be reset. You might need to
ask Lenovo Support for help, and perhaps pay for this support,
and will also need to show a proof of ownership of the computer.